# Cant install tensorflow-gpu in google colab, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory, machine-learning-model

When trying to install tensorflow to the gpu in google colab i get an error message.

[code being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evEQc.png)

I have looked at several forums and tutorials but i seem to be the only one getting this error message so i was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this. I am already connected to the gpu aswell.

Comment: You're not supposed to use tensorflow-gpu for tensorflow 2.x packages, I don't know if that is why you are getting an error, but you should probably just try tensorflow without the -gpu. If then go from there. Also, you can include the code you're using `pip install tensorflow-gpu` in the question and the error as text

Comment: I don't have to pip install anything, when I start a colab notebook, I can import tensorflow. I think you're trying to install the -gpu package and you're causing conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to install the `tensorflow-gpu` version in Google Colab explicitly. You can simply select **Hardware accelerator = GPU** and can use the tensorflow as GPU version in Google Colab.

Please follow this path to enable GPU mode in `Google Colab:

(Top Menu bar) **Select Runtime -> Change runtime type -> Hardware accelerator -> Select GPU -> Save**

Now run below code in Google Colab to check if GPU is enabled.

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

print("GPU:", tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print("Num GPUs:", len(physical_devices))
```

Output:

```
GPU: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
Num GPUs: 1
```